# Is there a way to exclude selecting currentDate from date picker component in UNQORK platform?

Tags: unqork

Even though we select custom filter to show future dates, there's a option still to select current date from the component.

Any help or alternative ways will really appreciate.

Comment: Hey sricharan! We have a private Stack Overflow team for questions about the Unqork platform. Please let me know if you have trouble accessing.

Comment: Hi Colton, can you help me in providing the path or URL for the same so that I can post my questions over there.

Comment: Absolutely! It's https://stackoverflow.com/c/unqork/questions